# How to insert a line before the FIRST and LAST matching pattern using sed

Tags: linux, bash, unix, awk, sed

I have a file: users.txt that looks like the below:

```
    Surname
    Surname
    Surname
    Age
    Age
    Age
```

I need to add **ONE** line with text: `Name` **ABOVE** wherever I find the **FIRST** occurrence of `Surname` so that the file looks like:

```
    Name
    Surname
    Surname
    Surname
    Age
    Age
    Age
```

I also need to be able to add **ONE** line with text: `Gender` **BELOW** wherever I find the **LAST** occurrence of `Age` so that the file looks like:

```
    Surname
    Surname
    Surname
    Age
    Age
    Age
    Gender
```

Currently I have these sed commands:

```
sed '/Surname/i \Name' user.txt
sed '/Age/a \Gender' users.txt
```

Though they are adding in new lines on **EVERY** match found.

Your time and assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean below the first or the last occurrence of `Age`? The question and the example output differ.

Comment: Yes apologies... should be the LAST occurrence....

Comment: Have edited my original, question. Thanks for spotting that :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how to do it in Perl

```sh
perl -nE'/Surname/&&($n++||say"Name")||($n=0);/Age/&&($g=1)||($g--&&say"Gender");print}{say"Gender"if$g'
```

And another way

```
perl -nE'/Surname/&&say("Name")..!/Surname/;/Age/&&($g=1)||($g--&&say"Gender");print}{say"Gender"if$g'
```

Comment: The Perl option seems a lot simpler than the others. Thanks for putting it up here. I have never used it before, I should explore it a little more.

Answer (score 4):

awk would be easier. Whenever I hear "do something on the LAST ..." I think "reverse the file, and do something on the FIRST ..."

```
file=users.txt
tmpfile=$(mktemp)

tac "$file" | 
awk '/Age/ && !found {print "Gender"; found=1} 1' | 
tac | 
awk '/Surname/ && !found {print "Name"; found=1} 1' > "$tmpfile" &&
mv "$tmpfile" "$file"
```

actually the sed is not that atrocious:

```
sed '
  /Surname/ {
    # we have seen the first pattern, insert the 1st new line
    i Name
    :a
    N                         # append the next line to pattern space
    $ {                       # if this is the last line
      s/.*Age\n/&Gender\n/    # add the 2nd new line after the last Age
      bb                      # and we are done: goto b
    }
    ba                        # goto a
    :b
  }
' users.txt
```

Comment: I liked the glowing review: `the sed is not that atrocious`. Sounds like the review for an Adam Sandler movie.... :-).

Answer (score 1):

With awk:

```
awk '/Surname/ && !s++ { print "Name" } /Age/ { a = 1; print; next } a && !f++ { print "Gender" } 1; END { if(a && !f) { print "Gender" } }' filename
```

This works as follows:

```
/Surname/ && !s++ {    # If Surname is found in a line and the flag for it
                       # is not set (i.e., if this is the first surname line),
                       # set flag and
  print "Name"         # print "Name"
}
/Age/ {                # if Age is found
  a = 1                # set flag for it
  print                # print the line
  next                 # and do nothing else for this line
}
a && !f++ {            # if the Age flag is set and (implicitly here) Age
                       # is not found in the line, and the flag that we
                       # already did this is not yet set, set the flag, and
  print "Gender"       # print Gender
}
1                      # then, finally, print the line from the input.

END {                  # if we reach the end without having printed the 
  if(a && !f) {        # gender line but found an Age block (that is, when the
                       # age block is at the end of the file)
    print "Gender"     # print it then.
  }
}
```

The `!s++` stuff is a way to check if a flag has not been set and set it in one go; I am told that this is idiomatic awk. If you're uncomfortable with it, you can also write

```
/Surname/ && !s { s = 1; print "Name" }
```

and so forth to have the same effect.

Comment: This will never print gender only after the first block of ages if there are any records between two ages it won't work, also won't print anything if age is on the last line.

Comment: I read the question so that there is only one block of ages, and that the whole point of the exercise is to keep the data organized that way. Good point about ending with the age block, though.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of ways you could do this but the one I prefer due to it's robustness, flexibility, clarity, simplicity, lack of code duplication, etc. is identifying the target lines on one pass and then using them on a 2nd pass:

```
gawk '
    NR==FNR { if (!first[$0]) first[$0]=NR; last[$0]=NR; next }
    FNR==first["Surname"] { print "Name" }
    { print }
    FNR==last["Age"] { print "Gender" }
' file file
```

Comment: Think the use of arrays for this are a bit overkill as there are only really two record numbers/variables that need to be set.Also it will not work for OPs example as you are saving $0 which contains spaces but searching for the exact names in the array.

Comment: Usually people post input with spaces because they couldn't figure out how to format it properly. I doubt if there are leading or trailing spaces in the real input files but I also don't know what the real input files really look like since the sample posted doesn't seem like a useful file so it's probably missing key information. Hopefully the OP can adapt whatever solutions are posted to match his real input. I don't know if the OP only has 2 keys to worry about, maybe this is just an example and he's looking for a general approach and this is one no-one else had thrown into the mix.

Answer (score 1):

This is how to insert a line with sed before last match.

```sh
sed -i -e '/**PATTERN**[^\n]*/,$!b;//{x;//p;g};//!H;$!d;x;i**TEXTOINSERT**' FILE
```

This is how to insert a line with sed before first match.

```sh
sed -i -e '/**PATERN**/{a\\**TEXTOINSERT**' -e ':a;n;ba}' FILE
```

Answer (score 0):

Awk
Sets the Record numbers of first occurence of Surname and last occurence of age, reads the file twice and prints stuff when it reaches set record numbers.

```
awk '/Surname/ && !s++{Sr=NR}/Age/{FNR==NR&&age=NR}
     FNR!=NR{print (Sr==FNR?"Name\n"$0:age==FNR?$0"\nGender":$0)}' test{,}

Name
    Surname
    Surname
    Surname
    Age
    Age
    Age
Gender
```